# Removing rows with dates within 4 or less days of each other Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove rows if Date is 4 or less days within  consecutive row Data value.
We want to keep the first row, and remove the other rows.

So below, 2018-02-20 is within 4 days of 2018-02-16 so we keep 2-16 but remove 2-20.
The tricky part is going to be we have to now adjust for the removal of 2-20 and now need to compare 2-16 with 2-21. It's 5 days (more than 4 so we keep), so we keep 2-21.

We remove 2-22 as it is one day within 2-21, but we keep 2-26 as it is over the 4 day limit above (when compared to 2-21).

So here is a sample dataframe I created

```
       Date       Open
0  2018-02-16  69.750000
1  2018-02-20  65.699997
2  2018-02-21  60.000000
3  2018-02-22  67.650002
4  2018-02-26  77.666666 
8  2018-03-01  73.500000
9  2018-03-02  66.750000
3  2012-09-28  0.500
4  2012-10-01  0.500
5  2012-10-02  0.575
6  2012-10-21  0.130
```

I want the result to be this, where the consecutive dates have a span of at least 4 or more days

```
0  2018-02-16  69.750000
2  2018-02-21  60.000000
4  2018-02-26  77.666666 
3  2012-09-28  0.500
6  2012-10-21  0.130
```

Comment: all i have think is using looping with if inside. have you try it? or you want the simplest syntax?

Comment: Actually I don't have any solutions.  Simpler the better, as I am very rusty with Pandas now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
class DateIntervalGenerator():
    date_state = None

    def __call__(self, date):
        if not self.date_state or abs(date-self.date_state) > pd.Timedelta('4D'):
            self.date_state = date
            return self.date_state


df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(DateIntervalGenerator())
df = df.dropna(subset='Date')
print(df)
>>>
    Date        Open
0   2018-02-16  69.750000
2   2018-02-21  60.000000
4   2018-02-26  77.666666
3   2012-09-28  0.500000
6   2012-10-21  0.130000
```

The above code defines a class named DateIntervalGenerator which is used to process the Date column. This class has the following functionalities:

1. Creates a class variable named date_state to store the most recently
   processed date.
2. An instance of this class can be called, which takes a date
   parameter and returns a date.
3. If date_state is empty or the difference between the new date and
   date_state is greater than 4 days, it updates date_state and returns
   the new date. Applies the DateIntervalGenerator instance on the Date
   column of the df and drops any rows that contain NaN to
   generate a dataset with consecutive dates.
4. Therefore, the purpose of this code is to generate a new date column
   in the df where the time interval between adjacent dates
   is no more than 4 days, and any rows containing NaN values are
   removed.

Comment: Thank you for this.
Just want to make sure I am understanding how the nan values 
are generated. 
So if date is not empty or interval isn't greater than 4,
it just returns a Nan value as you didn't specify anything to return.

Comment: Good Answer. @MasayoMusic - a function will by default return None if there is no explicit return expression. Hence the class function returns None if the condition is not met. The first part of the condition deals with the first row which has to be a special case.